# Pearson correlation coefficient and p-value

Tags: correlation, p-value

Can I reject null hypothesis only using p-value calculated for Pearson correlation coefficient or I should also check if Pearson correlation coefficient big enough?

I found in Scipy documentation ([http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~francois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/%7Efrancois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html)): "The p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than 500 or so.". But I have dataset with more than 500 samples.

I have an intuition that we can get small p-value even if we have big Pearson correlation coefficient, but can we get small Pearson correlation coefficient and big p-value?

Answer (score 1):

You would expect the p-value to decrease (easier to reject) as:

1. The Pearson correlation magnitude increases AND/OR
2. The sample size increases.

(This assumes a two-sided test. For a one-sided test, the correlation would have to move in the direction specified by the alternative hypothesis.)

Statistical significance has little to do with practical significance, however. All the hypothesis test does, loosely speaking, is tell you that you observed something unlikely if the null hypothesis is true; when that something is sufficiently unlikely, you doubt or even reject the null hypothesis. However, the null hypothesis is literal. When you test $H_0:\rho=0$, if you have evidence that $\rho = \text{ridiculously small, like 1/TREE(3)}$, that indicates an incorrect null hypothesis.